# Robocopy folder and subfolders and files WITHOUT permissions , only datas

Tags: robocopy

I'm currently doing a file server migration using Robocopy.

I used the following commands to copy the folder to new server WITHOUT security permissions.

I want to copy only folder & files / subdirectories.

When attempting to open folder on destination file server then it says "Unable to display current owner."

is it normal ?

NEW FILE SERVER :

[image]

```
ROBOCOPY "driveletter:\source\file directory\" "driveletter:\destination\file directory\" /xf "pagefile.sys" "thumbs.db" "*.tmp" /xd "DfsrPrivate" "recycler" "$RECYCLE.BIN" "System Volume Information" /MIR /ZB /MT:16 /R:1 /W:1 /NP /TEE /LOG:"C:\tmp\LogName.log"
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Robocopy doesn't copy security descriptors by itself. This means it copies the data of the files and folders, but it doesn't copy the information about who owns them and what permissions they have. This is why you see the "Unable to display current owner" message.

To copy the security permissions along with the data, you can use the /COPY:SD switch in your Robocopy command. This will copy the security descriptors (SDs) from the source files and folders to the destination.

Or if you only need access to the data itself and don't care about ownership or specific permissions, you can ignore the message and use the data as is. However, be aware that this might cause issues with certain applications or scripts that rely on specific permissions.

On the other hand, you can use copy tools such as Syncback or Gs Richcopy to perform this task easily.